# MongoDB cluster timeout while connecting to Node-RED

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-red

I am facing troubles while trying to connect my MongoDB:3.4 cluster to Node-RED:2 using Docker Swarm.

My environment consists of one leader machine, two workers with one Mongo node on each (`mongo1` and `mongo2`), and the Node-RED container on one of the workers.

I successfully initiated my cluster with the below command:

```
rs.initiate({
   _id : "rs1",
   members: [
      { _id: 1, host: "mongo1:27017" },
      { _id: 2, host: "mongo2:27017" }
   ]
})
```

A connection with Mongo Express was successful on both the primary and secondary nodes of my cluster.

But when I tried to connect to the cluster from node-RED using the [node-red-node-mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-node-mongodb) module, I got the following error:

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo2:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out
    at connectionFailureError (/data/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:362:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/data/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:330:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:495:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)]
```

This is how the MongoDB node was configured:

- Host: `mongo1,mongo2`
- Connection topology: `RelicaSet/Cluster (mongodb://)`
- Connection options: `replicaSet=rs1&tls=true&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true&wtimeoutMS=10000&slaveOk=true`

And these are the relevant parts of the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'


services:
  NodeRed:
    user: root
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    volumes:
      - /home/ssmanager/nfsdata/nodered:/data
      - /home/ssmanager/nfsdata/records:/data/records
      - /home/ssmanager/nfsdata/cdr:/data/cdr
      - /home/ssmanager/nfsdata/html/decrypted_temp:/data/records/decrypted
    image: nodered/node-red:2
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.hostname!=ssmanager3"
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        max_attempts: 5
 
 mongo1:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongod --replSet rs1 --noauth --oplogSize 3
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.mongo.replica == 1
          - "node.hostname!=ssmanager3"
          
  mongo2:
    image: mongo:3.4
    command: mongod --replSet rs1 --noauth --oplogSize 3
    environment:
      TERM: xterm
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.mongo.replica == 2
          - "node.hostname!=ssmanager3"

  express:
    container_name: express
    image: mongo-express:0.54.0
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: admin
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: password
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN: "true"
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo1
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongo:27017
      ME_CONFIG_REQUEST_SIZE: 100Mb
    command:
      - "mongo-express"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.hostname!=dcsynmgr01"
          - "node.hostname!=ssmanager3"
    ports:
      - target: 8081
        published: 8081
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host


networks:
  host_mode:
    external:
      name: 'host'
  mynetwork:
    attachable: true
```